# Select rows based on text matches with SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, select

I need to setup a SELECT query that will return rows based on matching strings in columns that have comma-delimited lists.

Here's an example of the data:

```
path               title            desc            type        feed_type   markets         tags
IMG_5639.jpg        Malta Title     description     photo       sheetfed    tobacco,education   gatefolds,accordian
IMG_5672.jpg        Malta Title     description     conceptual  inline      magazine        gatefolds,oversized
IMG_5689.jpg        Malta Title     description     conceptual  digital     non-profit      oversized
IMG_5691.jpg        Malta Title     description     photo       sheetfed    automotive      oversized,obtuse
IMG_5694.jpg        Malta Title     description     photo       inline      tobacco         postcard,oblong
IMG_5699.jpg        Malta Title     description     conceptual  digital     education       oversized,obtuse
IMG_5701.jpg        Malta Title     description     conceptual  sheetfed    service         postcard,oblong
01.jpg          Barcelona Title     barcelona       conceptual  sheetfed    service         diecut
02.jpg          Barcelona Title     barcelona       photo       inline      education       postcard,oblong
03.jpg          Barcelona Title     barcelona       photo       digital     associations        gatefolds,accordian
```

Comment: tip:  if this is your database schema, I would highly recommend that you not put CSV lists in a column.  It's an anti-pattern and difficult to query from SQL:  http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back

Comment: I've tried SELECT * FROM images WHERE tags LIKE 'diecut' AND tags LIKE 'oblong' expecting to get results that contain both. Seems like the 2nd LIKE has no effect on my results whatsoever.

If I do some like tag LIKE 'oversized,obtuse' it gets the results correctly. How ever LIKE 'obtuse,oversized' returns nothing though I would expect it return the same.

Comment: @BlueDude - that's because when you use the LIKE clause like this its doing raw text comparisons - there's nowhere in your above data where 'obtuse,oversized' occurs, so it won't return anything.  Good to have as part of your unit tests to work up to.

Comment: @BlueDude - It seems like a lot of your questions are very basic on this - I recommend reading this introduction to the LIKE operator:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp.  You also might want to read a general tutorial on writing SQL queries, like the one at w3schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Googling about the LIKE clause.

The comma-delimited bit shouldn't matter unless your user puts commas in their search query.

In which case, if you can change the database schema, I'd put each column of your CSV data into its own database column.  Which will allow you to query individually on each column.

Comment: Thank you I should have mentioned I tried the LIKE clause but couldn't get a query to successfully search for multiple terms at once. Unless I can get something figured out soon, I'm just going to create the other tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
 I think, you should normalized your data properly? A single column should never contain a comma seperated string of names.
otherwise in most cases you would not get proper output.
```

Comment: Thank you I understand that now. Im adding a couple of extra tables (tags and image_tags)one holds all the tags, so with image_tags I can enter an image_id and tag_id to associate them. I was trying to do a quick test and figured I could save some time if I just jammed it all into one table.

Comment: yeah, generally when you are designing schema never prefer column with comma separated object.